# What factors can change the HTML input byte stream?

Tags: javascript, html, dhtml, document.write

As I know, the HTML input is byte stream, and `document.write()` can change the stream by inserting new bytes. E.g.

```
document.write("<p> an example </p>");
```

Also the [parsing model](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/parsing.html) of HTML5 specification only indicate `document.write()` can change the HTML input, but it doesn't say it's the only factor.

Is there any other factors changing the HTML input ?

Answer (score 1):

There's [document.writeln](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/dom.html#document.writeln%28%29) as well, but that's it.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at their Tree model next to where they point out `document.write()` it shows that the script execution is handled outside of the actual tree creation. This means, I believe, that any script that manipulates the dom would be placed in the same place as `document.write()`.

These would include but not be limited to:

```
el.innerHTML = '';
el.innerText = '';
el.style = '';
el.insertBefore = '';
el.insertAfter = '';
el.createDocumentFragment;
el.appendChild();
el.removeChild(); //note this is the only supported way of removing from the html bit stream
document.write();
//and anything else that changes either the html, css or even other scripts in the 
//document.
```

Comment: @Bergi, I don't think your wrong, but how can that be? I mean if you create or insert something into your page, doesn't it have to be parsed by the html parser of the browser just like the original stream? As my answer shows I thought it always worked differently, so I would like to know what's happening if my idea is mistaken.

Comment: No, it is parsed once and then you only have the *Document **Object** Model* with its tree-structure. It might be possible to serialize the DOM back to a HTML string, but it won't be the same (different character entities, corrected parse errors etc); and sometimes the parser is needed again for `innerHTML` or such, but the original HTML string will have been forgotten.

Comment: @Bergi So how does the tree he linked to work then? I mean `document.write()` still has to wait for the dom to load, so if you had any of the above calls inserting or removing from the dom on `document.ready` wouldn't they then insert into the `Input Stream
Preprocessor` just like `document.write()`?

Comment: No. `document.write` happens during the parse, the `DOMready` event says "parsing ready, the full page can be accessed via DOM now"